# Fast Filter of Array With Respect to Another

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have an array of indexes, `A`.
Suppose I have an array `B`, where every key is an array containing some indexes or number.
I would know which of the entries in `B` contain some index appearing in `A`.
For example (in php style):

```
A = [3,45,67,8]
B = [ 1 => [1,6,8],
      2 => [5,67,3,4,5,66,6],
      3 => [55,56,57,58],
      4 => [45,80,81,82]
    ]
```

The entries of B which contain some value of A are 2 and 4.
So the function I would make should be:

```
function solution = filter(A,B) // solution = [2,4]
```

Now, with a brute loop, looping over entries of B, the complexity will be
`O(nm)`, where `n` is `#B` and `m` is the size of longest row in B.
There are smarter solutions?

Comment: If you transpose B such that for each value you keep a list of entries where it occurs and then use a Hash to store it, you'll have an initial complexity of $O(nm)$, but for all other operations you'd have a complexity of $O(1)$.
BTW this is more a programming question than a mathematics question

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, entry 1 in B shares value 8 with A, so it should be in the output solution ?